# How to open Jasper report (Book report like -wave book- ) using NetBeans Java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports, connection

How to open Jasper report (Book report like -wave book- ) using NetBeans Java code?
    wave book it is a template in jasper report it contain more than one page ,i Build the report in -TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio- and test it it run without any problem but when i try to run it from netbeans nothing happened , i did all the necessary connection and the code , the code work if other template (one page)

Comment: What's "wave book". A jasper report needs to be compiled, filled and exported before it can be displayed

Comment: wave book it is a template in jasper report it contain more than one page ,i Build the report in jasper report studio and test it it run without any problem but when i try to run it from netbeans nothing happened , i did all the necessary connection and the code , the code work if other template (one page)